# Is it possible to speed up the processing of this stored procedure from C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, database-performance

I call a SQL Server stored procedure from C#. As long as I set the `SqlCommand` `CommandTimeout` high enough, it works - returns data -- but it's slower than molasses at absolute zero.

Is there anything I can do in how I call the stored procedure that can speed up the process? I do it this way:

```
DataTable dtFillRateResults = SqlDBHelper.ExecuteSQLReturnDataTable(FILL_RATE_BY_DISTRIBUTOR_BY_CUSTOMER_STORED_PROC, CommandType.StoredProcedure,
            new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@Unit",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar,
                Value = _unit
            },
            new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@Member",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar,
                Value = _memberId
            },
            new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@BegDate",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime,
                Value = Convert.ToDateTime(_dateBegin)
            },
            new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@EndDate",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime,
                Value = Convert.ToDateTime(_dateEnd)
            }
);
```

The above calls `SqlDBHelper.ExecuteSQLReturnDataTable()`, which is:

```
public static DataTable ExecuteSQLReturnDataTable(string sql, CommandType cmdType, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
    using (SqlConnection connStr = new SqlConnection(FillRateRptConstsAndUtils.CPSConnStr))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connStr))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = EXTENDED_TIMEOUT;

        foreach (var item in parameters)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(item);
        }

        try
        {
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(ds);
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlex)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < sqlex.Errors.Count; i++)
            {
                var sqlexDetail = String.Format("From ExecuteSQLReturnDataTable(), SQL Exception #{0}{1}Source: {2}{1}Number: {3}{1}State: {4}{1}Class: {5}{1}Server: {6}{1}Message: {7}{1}Procedure: {8}{1}LineNumber: {9}",
                    i + 1, // Some users would get the fantods if they saw #0
                    Environment.NewLine,
                    sqlex.Errors[i].Source,
                    sqlex.Errors[i].Number,
                    sqlex.Errors[i].State,
                    sqlex.Errors[i].Class,
                    sqlex.Errors[i].Server,
                    sqlex.Errors[i].Message,
                    sqlex.Errors[i].Procedure,
                    sqlex.Errors[i].LineNumber);
                MessageBox.Show(sqlexDetail);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            String exDetail = String.Format(FillRateRptConstsAndUtils.ExceptionFormatString, ex.Message, Environment.NewLine, ex.Source, ex.StackTrace);
            MessageBox.Show(exDetail);
        }

        return ds.Tables[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't in the stored procedure itself? You may want to show the code for the SP, I can't see anything glaring in the C# code that would cause issues, this line `new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(ds);` looks odd, not that its wrong or an issue, but just sticks out.

Comment: If it's slow, it's the database's fault. You need to optimize the stored procedure (if possible).

Comment: This is most likely an issue with the system the DB is hosted on or the DB itself.

Comment: I agree with y'all; I am just wondering if there's anything I can do on my end to mitigate the slothlike attitude of the SP.

Comment: I don't think that adding `please` to your query is going get the DB to speed up.

Comment: Are the proper columns indexed in your database so that your queries are optimized and run to their full capabilities? Are the statistics up to date as well so the most efficient execution of the query can take place? Sometimes it's not the logic at fault, but the database itself.

Comment: If the upstream side is slow you aren't going to make it faster by working on the downstream side. You'll need to optimize the SP.

Comment: Only thing you could possibly do is avoid the SP all together and recreate the SP in C# (obviously without the issues the SP has) and see if that operates faster.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how much data are you returning anyway?

Comment: @PeterM: In the test scenario I'm running today, not much - it only returns 288 records of about a dozen fields each - a drop in the bucket, so to speak. And yet it takes 2-3 minutes to run!

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Have you run it by just calling the stored procedure on the database?  Is it slow there too?

Comment: Your database system (or the link to it), the table structure, or query have major issues.  None of that would be affected by your client program.

Comment: @thinklarge: I may not be trying the right thing, but I'm doing this is LINQPad:
var output = spName("PLATYPUS","42",Convert.ToDateTime("9/1/2014"),Convert.ToDateTime("9/30/2015"));
...and it takes forever and a day. And even when it finishes, it shows no data - it just says that it did finish.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon I'd go right into the database (I know how to do this in oracle and SQL) and run the procedure there.  Not in link pad.  You can call it from an editor using the same parameters, and it'll give you an idea of how long the raw procedure takes to run.  This will point you to where you need to optimize.

Comment: It's not mine to optimize; the database cat will do that.

Comment: If you do not have access/rights to optimize the stored procedure, tell the DBAs about it. If you have SQL Management Studio and access to run the stored procedure, do it and see how long it takes to execute. In my opinion the problem is in the SQL - you need to optimize it.

Comment: @Apostrofix: I only have the tools available from within Visual Studio. Can I use VIew > SQL Server Object Explorer for this? To answer my own question, it's actually View > Server Explorer that gets me where I can see and execute the SP...and it's still executing after quite awhile, so it's definitely the SP itself that's slow...